# Separate page for pagination possible?

Tags: pagination, page-template, get-template-part, post-content

This is how my index.php looks like for my custom theme (I'm not sure if Line 4-5 is necessary).

When I put pagination in the `home` or `post`, I would like to be able to take the user to a separate custom page with just the posts as the current `home` or `post` custom page has many `DIVs` that I don't want to show in the `/page/2/3/4` etc.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>
<?php if(is_home() || is_front_page()){ ?>
    <?php get_template_part('templates/content','home'); ?>
    <?php } else if (is_home()){ ?>
        <?php get_template_part('templates/content','home'); ?> <!-- home  -->
    <?php } else if (is_page()){ ?>
        <?php get_template_part('templates/content','page'); ?> <!-- page content -->
    <?php } else if (is_single()){ ?>
        <?php get_template_part('templates/content','post'); ?> <!-- post content -->
    <?php } else { ?>
        <?php get_template_part('templates/content','cat'); ?> <!-- category -->
    <?php } ?>
<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Basically, if someone clicks on Page 2/3/4 etc, I want them to see this new custom template part:

```
<?php } else if (is_paginated()){ ?>
  <?php get_template_part('templates/content','paginated'); ?>
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: You’re looking for is_paged()

Comment: Amazing!! Please post it as an Answer. Thank you :)